# Keras LSTM uni & bidirectional models converted to Tensorflowjs not producing correct inference

Tags: lstm, tensorflowjs-converter

**TensorFlow.js version used**

- tensorflow 1.12.0
- tensorflow-base 1.12.0
- tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0
- tensorflow-hub 0.2.0
- tensorflowjs 0.8.0

**Browser version used**

- Firefox 65.0 (64-it) on Windows 10
- Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 on Windows 10

**Problem Description**

I have created & trained a Keras based LSTM bidirectional model in Python to classify video. This model works awesome and classifies the videos with 90+ accuracy. **But when I converted this model to tensoflorjs model using the tensorflorjs_converter tool and used the same on browser, the model always throws the same output (top 3 results) for any video input** - BasketballDunk; prob. 0.860, BalanceBeam; prob. 0.088, BodyWeightSquats; prob. 0.024

I have checked all the inputs, their shape, etc. that are given to the LSTM bidirectional model and can't find any issues. But still the inference from LSTM bidirectional model is always the same irrespective of the video input. I have ensured that every individual video frame sent to LSTM model as a sequence is correct. (used MobileNet model to recognize each frame and it does correctly and hence concluding that frames sent to LSTM are perfect)
Please help me identifying the issue & fix. All the required details are below.

(entire model is based on the examples given in this github repository by Xianshun Chen (chen0040) ->[https://github.com/chen0040/keras-video-classifier])

**Details of the model:**

- uses MobileNet model to extract features
- uses LSTM bidirectional model to take-in extracted features and
  classify the video as one of 20 classes

**Dataset used:**

- UCF101 - Action Recognition Data Set
  (http://crcv.ucf.edu/data/UCF101.php)

**Tensorflowjs converted model:**

- tensorflowjs converted model, sample videos and html file to test are
  all in this drive location as zip file:
  [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k_4xOPlTdbUJCBPFyT9zmdB3W5lYfuw0]
- to test the model, just unzip and build using 'yarn' and run using
  'yearn watch'
- index.html has the instructions to test

**NOTE:** I have tried LSTM model (unidirectional) and same issue is with that converted model as well. Only difference is that it produces 'Billards' as the top prediction with probability over 0.95.

**Code to reproduce the issue:**
Code & test artifacts are in a zip file at this Drive location - [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k_4xOPlTdbUJCBPFyT9zmdB3W5lYfuw0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the reasons for tfjs converted model not producing the correct inference...at last :)

Reasons:

1. List item Input to LSTM model had NaN in them! Though I was passing the extracted features from MobileNet model to LSTM, features **.dataSync() was not used**. Because of this, when I added the extracted features into a tf.buffer they were added as NaN. (when I printed values in log just before adding to tf.buffer, they printed values correctly!...this is strange). So, when I used dataSync() on the extracted features, they got added into tf.buffer correctly.
2. List item **Use of tf.buffer() to store the extracted features** (from MobileNet) and converting them to tensors before passing to LSTM model. Instead I used tf.stack() to store the extracted features and then passed the stacked tensor to LSTM model. (I understand that tf.stack() does the equivalent of np.array())

Hope these inputs help someone.

Regards,
Jay